# Showing japanese, Bengali character in html label

Tags: jquery, html, c#-4.0, unicode-string

In my database some text are entry in japanese or bengali. When i retrieve the records and display in label then a garbage is showing.

How can i show any language text in my label? I am using c# & mvc

Thanks.

Comment: Does the rest of the page shows Japanese or Bengali font correctly ? If yes, any of those data come from database ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use google fonts, When choosing the font there is an option: Choose the character sets you want , There you can choose characters for Japanese or other languages. This is how i handled the same issue in my project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you have set content type properly.

> `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>`

Try one thing: Don't put it from db, try a plain Bengali/Japanese
    text as your title and see if shows correctly or not.

```
if it shows correctly, then the problem is related to your database:
```

2. See what character encoding is set for your columns/table from which
   you are trying to pull data from. if it is not set to support utf-8
   then you make sure that it supports.

   *define the relevant table as utf8 + collation utf8_bin.*
3. c) if it is set to utf-8 but still you are seeing this problem then
   it is due to the fact that you are pulling data without setting
   character set encoding in your connection string.

OK, so for C# client to read & write unicode values, you must include in the connection string: charset=utf8

for example: server=mysqlserver;user id=user;password=yourpassword;database=db123;charset=utf8;

4. Make sure your browser have the font that supports your intended language.